# pymongo date field converted to unknown date format

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, pymongo

I am getting data from one collection using python and I will be processing it and storing it in another collection. In the processed collection some of the date fields looks different like **Date(-61833715200000)**.

I use below code to get data and processing it and then I bulk insert the values to new collection.

```
fleet_managers = taximongo.users.aggregate([{ "$match": { "role" : "fleet_manager"}}])
fleet_managers = pd.DataFrame(list(fleet_managers))
fleet_managers['city_id'] = fleet_managers['region_id'].map({'57ff2e84f39e0f0444000004':'Chennai','57ff2e08f39e0f0444000003':'Hyderabad'})
pros_fleet_managers.insert_many(fleet_managers.to_dict('records'))
```

The collection looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58006678ee5e0e29c5000009"),
    "deleted_at" : NaN,
    "region_id" : "57ff2e84f39e0f0444000004",
    "reset_password_sent_at" : Date(-61833715200000),
    "current_sign_in_at" : ISODate("2016-10-14T06:07:55.568Z"),
    "last_sign_in_at" : ISODate("2016-10-14T06:07:45.574Z"),
    "remember_created_at" : Date(-61833715200000)        
}
```

What did do wrong here. Thanks already.

I have found the solution by using the **$ifNull** while projecting the fields.

```
fleet_managers = taximongo.users.aggregate([{ "$match": { "role" : "fleet_manager"}},{"$project":{'_id':1,'deleted_at':{ "$ifNull": [ "$deleted_at", "null" ] },
 'reset_password_sent_at':{ "$ifNull": [ "$reset_password_sent_at", "null" ] },                                  'region_id':1,'current_sign_in_at':1,'last_sign_in_at':1,'remember_created_at':{ "$ifNull": [ "$remember_created_at", "null" ] }}}])
fleet_managers = pd.DataFrame(list(fleet_managers))
fleet_managers['city_id'] = fleet_managers['region_id'].map({'57ff2e84f39e0f0444000004':'Chennai','57ff2e08f39e0f0444000003':'Hyderabad'})
pros_fleet_managers.insert_many(fleet_managers.to_dict('records'))
```

The above code gives the solution but I need to handle the null or non existence dynamically i.e., when fetching it from the source collection.

Help me out on this.